# Oracle functional index creation

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

How to create the functional index for below case.

> CREATE INDEX index1 ON table1(MIN(col1));

It is giving below error: `SQL Error: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here`

Pls help!

Comment: What are you trying to do? That index as written above makes no sense.

Comment: Do you want to cache the current minimum value across all rows for the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to get the minimum value for `col1` faster (as I assume you do), then you could use a *materialized view*:

```
create materialized view table1_mat
       refresh on commit 
       as
       select min(col1) min_col1
         from table1;
```

You obtain the minimum value for col1 then like so:

```
 select min_col1 from table1_mat;
```

Note however, while selecting the minimum value might be sped up, insert and update times on `table1` might become slower.

With *query rewriting*, it's even possible to use the materialized view without chainging the original query:

```
alter materiazlied view table1_mat enable query rewrite;
```

Then

```
select min(col1) from table1
```

should use the materialized view.

Comment: Thanks! But small correction in your create statement. `AS` should come after the `...commit`. :)

Comment: @MohamedSaligh: Thanks for pointing this out, it's corrected in the statement now.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to create an index on `col1` that will speed up queries like this one:

```
SELECT MIN(col1)
  FROM table1
```

then you do not need a functional index. Just create normal index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index1 ON table1(col1);
```

Creating a functional index on `MIN(col1)` - if ever possible - would cause the index to have the same value (the smallest value of `col1`) for every row. Such index would be completely useless.